# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Из письма в редакцию (пунктуация авторская):

> ...не знаю, как правильно назвать этот лаз? подкоп? тоннель? — с
>   ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.

А как правильно тут расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант я бы заменила первый знак вопроса на двоеточие (если прочитать с другой интонацией):
*...Не знаю, как правильно назвать этот лаз: подкоп? тоннель? — с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.*

Comment: Тогда так:
"... (-) не знаю, как правильно назвать этот лаз (подкоп, тоннель?): с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д., и т. п. (-)"

Comment: Автор сомневается, как назвать отверстие: лаз? подкоп? тоннель? А в предложении __inna__ уже никаких сомнений по поводу "лаз". Это нарушение авторского замысла. Нельзя двоеточие ставить.

Comment: В варианте  "... (-) не знаю, как правильно назвать этот лаз (подкоп, тоннель?): с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д., и т. п. (-)" для постановки двоеточия тоже никаких условий, кажется,  нет.

Answer (score 0):

Мне пунктуация в этом предложении нравится: всё верно. Тире отделяет однородные несогласованные определения от определяемого слова, а определяемое слово только одно из трёх предложенных, и неизвестно, к какому из них отнести определения. Знаки вопроса тоже смотрятся прекрасно. Хорошее предложение, не скучное.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза строго говоря не поддаётся идеальной корректорской правке, поскольку передаёт разговорную речь и не следут нормативной грамматике. 
Наиболее близко к правилам как-то так: **"... (-) не знаю, как правильно назвать этот лаз(?), подкоп(?), тоннель(?): с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д., и т. п. (-)"**

По правилам вопросительный знак возможен только в абсолютном конце предложения или перед закрывающей кавычкой или скобкой. При этом вся конструкция, начинающаяся со слов "не знаю...", производит впечатление вставной (без контекста не могу утверждать наверняка), и её хочется саму обсособить с помощью парных тире. Но тогда получится переизбыток тире, и имеющимся придется пожертвовать. Возможно, там по смыслу подойдёт двоеточие.

Между "и т. д." и "и т. п." необходима запятая.

PS Прошу не рассматривать представляемый вариант как законченную рекомендацию, это просто наводка, в каком направлении стоит подумать.

Comment: Согласна, контекста не хватает. В вопросе предложение почему-то приведено не с начала. А от   этого начала многое зависит.

Comment: Позвольте возразить Вам, behemothus, по поводу вопросительных знаков. Ставятся они не только в конце предложения, перед кавычкой или скобкой. 
http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/pvp.html; В вопросительных предложениях с однородными членами знак вопросительный может ставиться после каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса, например:

Да что мне до кого? до них? до всей вселенной? (Грибоедов).

Comment: Насколько понимаю, это у Грибоедова авторская вольность, никакими современными правилами и рекомендациями не предполагаемая.

Answer (score 0):

> ... не знаю, как правильно назвать этот... Лаз? Подкоп? Тоннель? С ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.

Пунктуация такая потому, что я воспринял предложение так (дополнив его до более полного разговорного стиля):

> ... не знаю, как правильно назвать этот *[, как его там]*... Лаз? Подкоп? Тоннель? *[Ну, который]* с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

*Хорошее предложение, не скучное.*

К авторской пунктуации я бы добавила троеточие перед "лаз" (остановилась, задумалась - как назвать?) и запятую:

**...не знаю, как правильно назвать этот... лаз? подкоп? тоннель? — с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д., и т. п.**

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что автор имел в виду: "Не знаю, как правильно назвать эту штуку: лаз, подкоп, тоннель? Она с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.

В этом случае предложение является безграмотным, даже с учетом разговорного стиля, и требует небольшиой правки.

Мой вариант:

**...не знаю, как правильно это назвать: лаз?, подкоп?, тоннель? — с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п.**

Впрочем, можно придумать контекст, оправдывающий авторский варинат:

**...не знаю, как правильно назвать этот...лаз?, подкоп?, тоннель? — с ответвлениями, глухими ветками, хитрыми ловушками и т. д. и т. п., — назвать его инженерным сооружением или просто достопримечательностью.**

Примечание (По поводу "и т. д. и т. п.")

Вопрос № 226937 (Грамота.ру)
Вот еще какой вопрос - если перечисление заканчивается так: "и т. д. и т. п." (именно в сокращенном вар-те), нужна ли запятая перед вторым союзом "и"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка: 
Запятая не нужна.

Comment: И т.д. и т.п. - вопрос, конечно, интересный.  А Википедия утверждает, что запятая нужна: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова _Википедия утверждает, что запятая нужна_ Нет, там через запятую перечислены два отдельных сокращения. Это понятно по другим строкам таблицы и по примеру для этой строки.